# ChromeDriver Not Reachable Exception

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I'm running my automation tests on Jenkins, and some times my tests start getting skipped because of this Exception: `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable`. And I'm clueless of what could be causing it. My Chrome Driver version is the 2.9 and my selenium-java is 2.40.

Also I get and error on the following test `handleTestMethodName` which is of testNG framework. If any faced a similar issue and feels like shedding some light would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: this is the stacktrace of the exception thrown and the Jenkins version is 1.523:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 61.17 seconds
Build info: version: '2.40.0', revision: '4c5c0568b004f67810ee41c459549aa4b09c651e', time: '2014-02-19 11:13:01'
System info: host: 'MVDSQA2W7', ip: '10.64.70.16', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:573)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.startSession(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:117)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:160)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:128)
    at com.verifone.test.cases.utils.AccesoWeb.initializeSelenium(AccesoWeb.java:88)
    at com.verifone.test.cases.utils.AccesoWeb.handleTestMethodName(AccesoWeb.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:543)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:212)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:631)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:883)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1208)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:758)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:613)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:87)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1062)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:974)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:178)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually happens when chrome is killed and the driver object is trying to do something..does it always happen at the same point?  then could be something in the code structure..paste the stacktrace..for someone to be able to help you.

Comment: What Chrome Version? What version of Jenkins? What testing framework is being used to run them? What version of Windows?

Comment: Added the Stacktrace. The chrome version im using is the 2.9 the latest and the jenkins version is the 1.523. The testing framework is TestNG.

Comment: Please share your code which you have written to initiate chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue and got solved by  below steps

1. Download latest chrome driver from http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
2. Paste the driver inside the project path
3. Add setProperty of chromedriver as below

> System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");

4. Initialize the driver

> driver= new ChromeDriver();